# Convert Large Decimal Number to String in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have large decimal numbers which I am getting from a request & I want to convert them to string. 
So for EG:

I tried all methods converting to string

```
var r=12311241412412.1241523523523235
        r.toString(); 
        r+'';
        ''+r;
        String(r);
//output
'12311241412412.1241'
//what i want
'12311241412412.1241523523523235'
```

All methods return the decimal numbers upto 4 digits (12311241412412.1241)
but i want all the number till end. 
I also tried r.toFixed().toString() but each time the length of decimal numbers change.

What would be easy way to do this?

Comment: I don't think JS can handle such a large number with that precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that `12311241412412.1241523523523235` in javascript means `12311241412412.125`. whatever you do is not gonna work unless you put the whole thing in a string at the first place.

use this instead:

```
var r = "12311241412412.1241523523523235";
```

Comment: OP said that he is getting it from the request

Comment: @SagarV : Right..!!

var r = request.id   /// response

Comment: first log on console the value and make sure you got it properly

Comment: @Ritwikga What is `request`, where does it come from? Who generated that number value? JS *cannot represent* such precise numbers.

Comment: it does not matter where it gets it from. as long as it's a Number javascript will change it to what you see once it parsed. So only way to make it the original value is to just not parse it at all (keeping it as a string). if you want mathematical operations, then you can use libraries that are out there just for this purpose.